# changing electrical plugs

Tags: electrical

I'm planning on buying a solder iron from ebay, the device has a US plug but it uses 220V-240V
I know US outlets only uses 110V.
What I want to know is just because they change the plug to a american plug is it safe to use?
Will changing the plug automatically convert it to 110 V?

Comment: US has 110, 220 and 3 phase...

Comment: Save  your money, don't buy a soldering iron.  Mains electrical power doesn't use solder.  That's for little tiny electronics projects.   Oh, you mean the *soldering iron* has the wrong plug?  LOL DON'T BUY IT, it's junk obviously if they can't be bothered to put the right plug on.

Comment: it's probably safe, but that doesn't mean that it will work well, more details are needed.

Comment: The latest batch of "936D" knock-offs (original was "Hakko 936D" - a model discontinued years ago) seem to support 110-240V if they are as good as the previous batch of single voltage "936D" knock-offs they may be worth a look.

Answer (score 7):

### Don't buy anything mains on eBay

Anything that plugs into mains power should have been certified by a competent testing lab, such as Underwriter's Laboratories (UL), ETL/Intertek, or CSA.  *Note that CE is not a testing lab*.

The Chinese make what can best be described as <s>sh**</s> a *junkstream* of extremely low-quality, dangerous garbage.  They would never waste the testing fee to send it to UL to get listed; they're deliberately breaking every rule in the UL White Book with regards to product safety. In fact, they usually don't fake a UL stamp; they put the CE stamp, which is a meaningless mark intended for products in Europe (where even there it's a voluntary mark; the company swears it self-inspected.)

This ... *junk*stream can be seen on full display on a site called alibaba.com, and you see the prices are preposterously low. This is because they are essentially counterfeit items.   They are also sold at retail at AliExpress.com. and also by enterprising marketers (most of them in China) who buy up lots of these items and list them on eBay.   At *much, much* higher prices.

They'll buy a $2 knockoff of a $30 item, and list it for $21 because *if they listed the item for $5, people would instantly realize it's a fake*.

The markup is so stupid high that they don't care about returns.

Those marketers also list them on a flea market called Amazon Marketplace, which is sneakily mixed into regular Amazon listings. (under the "Buy" button they say "Sold by XXXXXX" instead of Amazon). Amazon also allows them to dropship into Amazon's warehouse, in which case they say "...and fulfilled by Amazon" and ship with Prime.  Watch out.

Most countries in the world use 220V.  These cheap factories on Alibaba may not want to make a 120V version of their 220V junk, but if you order in large enough quantity, they'll happily slap a USA 120V plug on it.  And the marketers are too stupid to realize it's not that simple.

Now granted, eBay and Amazon have *everything* for sale, and that does include bona-fide parts.  So yes, it's possible to find the real McCoy, but you have to know exactly what you're looking for, and it's the very height of *caveat emptor*.  Buyer beware!

### The US also has 220V if you need it

If you have a bona-fide 220V item, that's actually doable. The US has plugs and sockets for that, and they're a different shape so you can't accidentally plug one into the other.  You wouldn't do that *just to save money* on a cheap soldering iron; you'd do that to use a special or exotic piece of equipment, like that perfect coffee machine.

Comment: I wouldn't say *anything* - I have bought quite a few things on eBay that plug into mains electrical and are 100% UL Listed and safe. But I know what I am looking for (typically used equipment that I get for parts because ordering replacement parts from HP or Dell or other big tech. companies often costs **far more** than buying an entire used computer system and salvaging what I actually need). But I'm not your average end-user. eBay is no better or worse (except for volume) than buying at a flea market or rummage sale, except that there you can inspect hands-on before you buy.

Comment: @manassehkatz good point.  Edited.  But not one that applies to OP, that's for sure. NEMA 5-15 on a 240V appliance lol...

Comment: Most of this answer seems to be a rant about low-quality knockoffs, which if off-topic

Comment: The CE mark is *not* voluntary in Europe.  It is illegal to sell stuff without it.  (You are right that it is self-certified though.)

Comment: "where even there it's a voluntary mark; the company swears it self-inspected" That doesn't make the mark voluntary. There are multiple directives (laws) in the EU that enforce CE markings. Without CE marking, it's not allowed on the EU market. Nothing voluntary about that. Which directive is applicable depends a bit on the hardware, but for machinery it's the 2006/42/EC and for a soldering iron it's probably the Low Voltage Directive 2006/95/EC. While a lot goes wrong with those self-certifications, it's absolutely not voluntary.

Answer (score 3):

No, a soldering iron that is designed to 220-240V (and probably 50Hz) will very likely NOT work properly at 110-120V 60Hz even if you do change the plug.

You could probably buy a step-up (120-240V) transformer and run it that way but I think you will offset any savings you are getting on this particular item.

It's my recommendation that you buy a 120V 60Hz soldering iron if you are planning on using it in the USA.

Comment: Are heating elements affected by a change of frequency like motors can be?

Comment: @SolarMike Heating elements are not (generally) affected by frequency. But they are **absolutely** affected by voltage.

Comment: @manassehkatz-ReinstateMonica I know that, I was wondering if the poster of the answer knew but you messed that up.....

Comment: @SolarMike Sorry about that. So then better would be to state the power issue specifically - 1/2 the voltage on a resistive heater (aka soldering iron) is 1/4 the power = 1/4 the heat = won't work very well.